# calcular potencia de 2 elevado a un numero especifico. javascript

Tags: javascript, bucles, while, operador

tengo un ejercicio resuelto de un bucle que retorna la potencia de 2 según el numero que nosotros coloquemos ( ej: elegimos el 3... 2³=8) pero no logro entender la solución al problema, ¿donde ocurre la operación de elevar el 2 al numero elegido? espero su ayuda

```
const output = powerOfTwo(10);

console.log(ouput); // -> 1024

const powerOfTwo = (number) => {
 let result = 1;

  while (number > 0) {
    result *= 2;
    number -= 1;
  }

  return result;
};

module.exports = powerOfTwo;
```

Comment: si elegis el numero 3 por ejemplo, la operacion seria 3 elevado al cuadrado no al reves como pusiste en tu ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

La definición de una potencia es:

> La potencia de una expresión algebraica es la misma expresión o el resultado de tomalrla como factor dos o más veces.

[Fuente](http://ingenieria.aragon.unam.mx/fesarbook/uploads/libros/31/pdf/Exponentes_y_Radicales.pdf).

Dicho de otra forma, el resultado de una potencia será multiplicar el mismo valor n veces.

Según el código que pones, lo que se hace es multiplicar 2, n veces según el número `number` de entrada. Esto se logra con el operador de asignación `*=` el cuál asigna el resultado de multiplicar por el operando de la derecha (en este caso es dos, siempre). Esta operación se realizará siempre y cuando `number` sea mayor a cero y se irá reduciendo en uno en cada iteración.

Tomando tu ejemplo de 10^2, el código hará lo siguiente: `2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2=1024`.

Teniendo claro lo que es una potencia y el funcionamiento del código original, bastará con hacer una pequeña modificación para poder sustituir el exponente (que no siempre sea 2).

```js
const powerOfN = (base, exponent) => {
  let result = 1;

  while (exponent > 0) {
    result *= base;
    exponent -= 1;
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(powerOfN(2, 10)); // 1024
console.log(powerOfN(10, 2)); // 100
console.log(powerOfN(3, 2));  // 9
console.log(powerOfN(2, 3));  // 8
```

Lo anterior realiza el comportamiento que hemos descrito anteriormente, multiplicar la base (`base`), n (`exponent`) veces.